# How to animate item update when using ViewPager2 with RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-viewpager2, android-pagetransformer

I need to animate a particular item update. In RecyclerView we can use ItemAnimator for such animation. What can we use for ViewPager2?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `ViewPager2.PageTransformer`, to animate the Fragments when they are swapped between.

Here is a link containing some cool animation.
Due note these are for `ViewPager` not `ViewPager2`, so you will have to modify them a bit. Luckily the interface has same signatures so it should be straight forward.

I've personally used two of them and they work great.

The only thing you will have to look out for is depth based animations `TranslationZ` those require API 21, if that's an issue for you.

https://www.loginworks.com/blogs/how-to-make-awesome-transition-effects-using-pagetransformer-in-android/

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, it is useful when we scroll the page (left or right) but does not work for item update. I need something like https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DefaultItemAnimator so that I can override animateChange function

Comment: @avalerio can you please check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70593277/11560810)